# Can I generate a READER_ID outside of the AMP ecosystem?

Tags: amp-html

I am using a third party company to show metering (free articles view count) to non-logged-in users. The third party company checks a user's log-in state by checking the READER_ID provided by the AMP ecosystem.

The problem is, users can be already logged-in from various non-AMP channels (cookies, tokens, etc). Therefore, they will not have the READER_ID available. My question is: Is there a way to generate a READER_ID outside of the AMP ecosystem, so that the third party company can track the user's state?

```
<script id="amp-access" type="application/json">
    {
        "authorization": "https://sandbox.tinypass.com/xbuilder/experience/executeAmp?protocol_version=1&aid=<YOUR_AID>&reader_id=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL&referer=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
        "noPingback": "true",
        "login": {
            "sign-in": "https://publisher.com/amp-login.html?reader_id=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL&_=RANDOM",
            "sign-out": "https://publisher.com/amp-logout.html?reader_id=READER_ID&_=RANDOM",
            "subscribe": "https://publisher.com/amp-subscribe.html?reader_id=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL&_=RANDOM"
        },
        "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
            "error": true
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing.
You say that the problem is that "users can be already logged-in from various non-AMP channels (cookies, tokens, etc.). Therefore, they will not have the READER_ID available."

In fact, the amp ecosystem generates always a READER ID, even if the user is not logged in. The Reader ID is constructed on the user device and intended to be long-lived. However, it follows the normal browser storage rules. So if the user enters in incognito, or deletes cookies, amp ecosystem gives to the user another Reader ID, and the third party company will not track the user's state.

It has its flaws.